# Copy formula from Excel to Notepad++

Tags: excel, excel-formula, notepad++

I tested some kinds of copying - but i copy just values instead formulas. Is there any way to copy Excel formula from multiple cells and paste it into a text document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to `Formulas` card, inside `Formulas Auditing` section there is a button `Show Formulas`.

[image]

Once you enabled it (clicked on it) you'll be able to copy formula from `Excel` to `Notepad ++`.

Comment: This does not work in Excel Online :(

Answer (score 1):

- In Excel, choose Options from the Tools menu.  Excel displays the
  Options dialog box. Make sure the View tab is selected.
- Ensure that
  the Formulas check box is selected.
- Click on OK. Excel should now be
  displaying formulas.
- Select the cells whose formulas you want to copy
  to Notepad.
- Press Ctrl+C to copy the cells to the Clipboard.