# Copying formulas from Excel to a text editor doesn't work reliably

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728456/copy-formula-from-excel-to-notepad), I want to copy formulas from Excel and paste them into a text editor. Strangely, I cannot get a reliable result from the answer in the linked question (ribbon's Formulas tab > Formula Auditing section > Show Formulas).

- Sometimes the Show Formulas command works as expected, with copied cells pasting as formulas.
- Other times, Show Formulas shows the formulas, but when pasting into the text editor, I get values not formulas.

Any next steps to fix the problem, or at least narrow down the cause? I can't spot a pattern in when it works and when it doesn't. I have Office 365.

Comment: I tried this with several different ranges selected and no problems using Office 365 Excel Version 2008 (Build 13127.21624 Click-to-Run), Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel. and NP++ v7.9.5 32 Bit. Also Win 10 21H1 Pro (19043.1052 - June Updates) HTH

Comment: Why would you want to copy them to a text editor? Anyway. Have you looked into `=FORMULATEXT(your_cell)`?

Comment: Do `Ctrl + \`` (grave accent, not single quote)

Comment: I usually want to show formulas then copy-paste so that I can edit an entire array of related formulas in a text editor. Could the random results be related to what file it is? 

I (the original poster) have Office 365 Excel version 2104 (Build 13929.20408 Click-to-Run), Monthly Enterprise Channel, NP++ v7.9.5 64-bit, and Windows 10 Pro 20H2 build 19042.1052.